# Session is not accepted by query

Tags: eloquent, datatable, laravel-10

I have a function that contains a query and checks within the query whether a session exists.
The following is stored in the session (whereNull('order_id')). I need to store this in a session because this query is needed more often and can also change.

To display the data I use DataTable.js

**Function:**

```
 public function index(Request $request)
 {
     if ($request->ajax()) {

         $data = Order::select('*')
             ->where('status', '!=', 'close')
             ->when(session()->has('order_id'), function ($query) {
                 return $query->session('order_id');
             })
             ->get();

         return Datatables::of($data)
             ->addIndexColumn()
             ->make(true);
     }
     return view('orders.index');
 }
```

**Error message:**

> DataTables warning: table id=ordersTable - Ajax error.
> For more information about this error,
> please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Do you have an idea how I can optimise the query so that the session can be read?